# Noughts and Crosses Tkinter project

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Alright so basically I've been set a task by my Tutor to create a GUI based Python game of Noughts and Crosses **without using classes**, so far here's what I've come up with. One question I have is how can I make it so every turn it toggles the player to "X" then the next "O" so that they can take turns, I have tried a lot of methods but I need help haha.
Thanks!

**Here's the Code:**

```
player = "O"
from tkinter import *

game = Tk()
game.title("Noughts and Crosses")

game.geometry("")

app = Frame(game)
app.grid()

def tl():
    topLeft.configure(text = player)

def tm():
    topMid.configure(text = player)

def tr():
    topRight.configure(text = player)

def ml():
    midLeft.configure(text = player)

def mm():
    midMid.configure(text = player)

def mr():
    midRight.configure(text = player)

def bl():
    botLeft.configure(text = player)

def bm():
    botMid.configure(text = player)

def br():
    botRight.configure(text = player)

#Top Row
topLeft = Button(app, text = "-", activebackground="red", command=tl)
topLeft.grid(row = 0, column = 0, ipadx=20, ipady=18, padx=10, pady=10)

topMid = Button(app, text = "-", activebackground="red", command=tm)
topMid.grid(row = 0, column = 1, ipadx=20, ipady=18, padx=10, pady=10)

topRight = Button(app, text = "-", activebackground="red", command=tr)
topRight.grid(row = 0, column = 2, ipadx=20, ipady=18, padx=10, pady=10)

#Middle Row
midLeft = Button(app, text = "-", activebackground="red", command=ml)
midLeft.grid(row = 1, column = 0, ipadx=20, ipady=18, padx=10, pady=10)

midMid = Button(app, text = "-", activebackground="red", command=mm)
midMid.grid(row = 1, column = 1, ipadx=20, ipady=18, padx=10, pady=10)

midRight = Button(app, text = "-", activebackground="red", command=mr)
midRight.grid(row = 1, column = 2, ipadx=20, ipady=18, padx=10, pady=10)


#Bottom Row
botLeft = Button(app, text = "-", activebackground="red", command=bl)
botLeft.grid(row = 2, column = 0, ipadx=20, ipady=18, padx=10, pady=10)

botMid = Button(app, text = "-", activebackground="red", command=bm)
botMid.grid(row = 2, column = 1, ipadx=20, ipady=18, padx=10, pady=10)

botRight = Button(app, text = "-", activebackground="red", command=br)
botRight.grid(row = 2, column = 2, ipadx=20, ipady=18, padx=10, pady=10)

game.mainloop()
```

Comment: Right now I am trying to figure out how to make it so the boxes when clicked once turn to noughts then when its player 2's turn when they click it is crosses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function to change `player`. You have to use keyword `global` to inform function that you use external/global variable when you use `=`. Without `global` it will create local variable and it will not change external `player`

```
def change_player():
    global player

    if player == 'O':
        player = 'X'
    else:
        player = 'O'
```

And then use this function in all your functions - like this:

```
def tl():
    topLeft.configure(text = player)
    change_player()
```

---

BTW: to make code more readable put `import` at the beginning and all functions before `game = Tk()`.

You could use `for` loop to create all buttons and keep them on linst `button[0]`, `button[1]`, etc. And then you could create only one function which you could assign to all `Button`. (but it will need `lambda` to assign function with argument)

Comment: BTW: you don't check if button is `-` so you can change button from `X` to `O`

Answer (score 0):

x_turn = True

while not game_over:
    turn = 'X' if x_turn else 'O'

```
# Your one-move code goes here

# At the bottom of the loop:
x_turn = not x_turn
```